# Next.js run build and routing issues for static website deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im working on this next.js webpage and I want it so that on npm run build, it will produce a production ready build that can be hosted as any normal vanilla html, js and css built page. As in the out folder generated on build can be uploaded on any server. For example, if the client has a [www.site.com/mysite/](http://www.site.com/mysite/) my project named landingPage will be served on [www.site.com/mysite/landingPage/](http://www.site.com/mysite/landingPage/)

However my current project will redirect to [www.site.com/mysite](http://www.site.com/mysite) when I use any Next  component with href='/' when the desired outcome is [www.site.com/mysite/](http://www.site.com/mysite/). I've tried using trailingSlash: true but since the website will only have a series of single static web pages, I would prefer not to set the exportPathMaps, although if I have to I want to know why this is necessary when without setting the trailingSlash as true, Next is capable of generating all the pages automatically on default.

Another issue is that it will serve and any subsequent pages eg  as [www.site.com/about](http://www.site.com/about) when I want it to be served as [www.site.com/mysite/about](http://www.site.com/mysite/about).

Some limiting parameters;

1. Preferably the solution should not require me to set a fixed basePath because I will not know where the client hosts the website. This solution has to assume I do not know that [www.site.com/mysite/](http://www.site.com/mysite/) will be the place where the site will be hosted. As far as Im concerned, the site will be named landingPage when Im developing it.

package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build && next export",
"export": "next export",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"},
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {reactStrictMode: true,};

module.exports = nextConfig;

const path = require("path");

module.exports = () => ({
basePath: "",
assetPrefix: ".",
sassOptions: {
includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
},
images: {
unoptimized: true,
},
});
```